# attaching handler that returns a value to an event c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have the following:

```
    public String AttachService(string whereClauseParam)
    {
        //Get Client object here
        Client c = new Client();
        string cookieFromRequest =   WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie];
        tokenInfo.TryGetValue(cookieFromRequest, out c);
        string[] arr = new string[] { };
        c.AttachedServiceStatus += OnAttachedServiceStatus;
        string whereClause = whereClauseParam.ToString();
        //c.AttachService("binding.interface='query_em'", 8799989);

        return string.Format("attached");
    }
```

//Handler code below:

```
    public string OnAttachedServiceStatus(Client sender, ClientServiceAttachedStatus status)
    {
        if (status.AttachStatus == AttachedStatus.Connected && status.ServiceAttachStatus == ServiceAttachStatus.Attached)
        { 
            //update the Client object in Dictionary
            Client c = new Client();

            var ou = tokenInfo.First(x => x.Value == sender);
            tokenInfo.TryGetValue(ou.Key.ToString(), out c);
            tokenInfo.TryRemove(ou.Key.ToString(), out c);
            tokenInfo.TryAdd(ou.Key.ToString(), sender);

            string[] statusInfoT = new string[200];
            statusInfoT[0] = status.ServiceId.ToString();
            statusInfoT[1] = status.AttachStatus.ToString();
            statusInfoT[2] = status.ServiceAttachStatus.ToString();
            statusInfoT[3] = status.VirtualServiceId.ToString();
            statusInfoT[4] = status.AttachToken.ToString();
            statusInfo.TryAdd(ou.Key.ToString(), statusInfoT);

            //update the UI with a Dispatch - TO BE DONE

        }

        return "Connected";
    }
```

The above AttachService method has a handler "OnAttachedServiceStatus" attached to an event "AttachedServiceStatus".
As long as the OnAttachedServiceStatus return void, it all works well. However, i now need to have the Handler OnAttachedServiceStatus to return a string but i'm not able to attach the handler correctly.

I'm thinking of using the Func delegate but not sure how to use it.
Please Help!

Comment: Return it to where, exactly? there is a reason why event handlers are void, and that reason is that your code doesn't call them, so there is no code to return a value to.

Comment: I want the handler "OnAttachedServiceStatus" to return a string back to Caller "AttachService" but i cannot get the following correct

Comment: c.AttachedServiceStatus += OnAttachedServiceStatus;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, signature of event handler is defined by event's delegate type. If that delegate returns `void`, then you cannot attach any other methods. Both parameters of method and return value should match signature of even's delegate. I believe `AttachedServiceStatus` uses delegate which returns `void`. Something like that:

```
public delegate void Action<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

And event is

```
public event Action<Client, ClientServiceAttachedStatus> AttachedServiceStatus
```

But what if you'll use delegate which returns value? E.g.

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

You can declare event as

```
public event Func<Client, ClientServiceAttachedStatus> AttachedServiceStatus
```

But it makes no sense. Because event is a delegate. When you attach handler, you are actually combining delegates, creating something like list of delegates (invocation list). This list contains all attached handlers. When you raise event, all handlers in invocation list are invoked one by one, and only result of last invoked handler is returned. Order of invokation is not determined. So you even don't know which handler returned value.

(*) Though it is still possible to get all results if you will invoke each handler manually instead of raising event. See Servy comment below

---

UPDATE

> I want the handler "OnAttachedServiceStatus" to return a string back
>   to Caller "AttachService" but i cannot get the following correct

When you attach handler to event, handler is not executed. It just added to invocation list of event. Event handler will be executed when `Client` will *raise* event. So `AttachService` is not a caller here. `Client` is a caller. And you cannot return string back to `AttachService`. After attaching handler to event, code will exit `AttachService` method. Some time later event will be raised, and handler will be executed, but it will not be related to `AttachService` method.

Comment: While the *default* behavior would indeed just give you a random value, you could not use the default add/remove handlers, or not simply call `Invoke` to invoke the handlers, and instead break them apart and call them individually.  It's very atypical, and unlikely to be appropriate for most situations, but it's not *impossible*.  All that said, the OP appears to not own the class defining the event in the first place, he's trying to provide a value to the code that attached the handler, not the code invoking the event, so none of this is actually relevant to him.

Comment: @Servy good point on manual delegates invocation. But what do you mean by *he is trying to provide a value to the code that attached the handler*? As I understand he tried to attach handler with wrong signature, which is impossible as I stated above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877040/attaching-handler-that-returns-a-value-to-an-event-c-sharp/41877212?noredirect=1#comment70936377_41877040

Comment: Sergey thank you for your comment. Actually, AttachedServiceStatus event is set in a Wrapper class that i have no access to and hence can't modify the delegate.

Comment: @RookieDude sorry, missed your comment - updated answer

Comment: @Servy that comment was added *after* my answer. No reason to downvote

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy How does that matter?  Your answer is still wrong in its answer to the question you thought the question was asking, and it still doesn't answer the question the OP is actually asking.

Comment: I voted Sergey's answer as it was helpful to my understanding of Events and Delegates. Though it didn't give me an solution to my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're understanding how events work.

```
    Client c = new Client();
    // ...
    c.AttachedServiceStatus += OnAttachedServiceStatus;
```

OnAttachedServiceStatus is not being called here. Instead, this is telling the Client object to invoke the OnAttachedServiceStatus method whenever it raises the AttachedServiceStatus event, which may happen at any point in the future. It's like you telling a racer "When I say 'go', run as fast as you can to the finish line then tell me how many steps it took you to get there". The racer doesn't immediately start running at that point, nor do they tell you how many steps it took; they get in the ready position and wait. When you say "go", that's when they execute your instructions and start running. By the time you get their response, it's well after you gave him the instruction to wait.

From the looks of things, you're attempting to establish a remote connection and are wanting confirmation back from the server that a connection has indeed been established. If using events to convey that information, you'll want to use the EventArgs to carry it. You should be able to achieve that with something like this:

Client side:

```
public String ConnectToServer(string whereClauseParam)
{
    //Create Server object here
    Server s = new Server();
    s.AttachedServiceStatus += OnAttachedServiceStatus;
    s.AttachService(this, whereClauseParam, 8799989);
}


public void OnAttachedServiceStatus (object sender, ClientServiceAttachedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AttachStatus == AttachedStatus.Connected && e.ServiceAttachStatus == ServiceAttachStatus.Attached)
    { 
        // Update the UI with the message from the server.
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

        // If you need to do something else with the server in response, you can do this:
        ((Server)sender).Foo("bar");
    }
}
```

And on the server side, define the custom EventArgs class for your event:

```
// By making this inherit from EventArgs, we can use the built-in EventHandler<T> delegate for the event itself.
public class ClientServiceAttachedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public AttachedStatus AttachStatus { get; set; }
    public ServiceAttachStatus ServiceAttachStatus  { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    // You can put in as many properties as you want to carry the information back from the server.
}
```

And put this in your Server class:

```
public event EventHandler<ClientServiceAttachedEventArgs> AttachedServiceStatus;

public String AttachService(Client client, string whereClauseParam, int code)
{
    // Do what you need to do to register the client.
    //...

    // Assuming everything went as planned, fire the event.
    // First, construct the EventArgs with information about the results of the connection.
    ClientServiceAttachedEventArgs e = new ClientServiceAttachedEventArgs();
    e.AttachStatus = AttachedStatus.Connected;
    e.ServiceAttachStatus = ServiceAttachStatus.Attached;
    e.Message = "Attached";

    // This is where your OnAttachedServiceStatus method in the client finally gets called. If the event handler were returning a string, this is where it would be returned to and I can't imagine this does you any good. 
    AttachedServiceStatus(this, e); 
}
```

This is a fairly basic implementation and your situation is probably more complex but it should point you in the right direction. The important thing to note is that the string that you wanted returned back to the client is coming through the event as part of the ClientServiceAttachedEventArgs, along with your status enums. This is the preferred way of sending information through events.